# Implement ChaCha20-Poly1305 in OpenSSL on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache, encryption, openssl, protocols

i would like to implement the `CHACHA20-POLY1305`-Cipher into my Apache2.4.10 with mod_ssl on Windows

I use Apache on Win64 with `mod_ssl` and the OpenSSL library `1.0.2d`
with `LibreSSL-Extension`. So when i now type the command `version` into openssl.exe, it shows up with LibreSSL v2.1.6. OpenSSL's and LibreSSL's Librarys are located in the `bin` folder from apache.

The problem is that openssl now knows the `CHACHA20-POLY1305`-Cipher but Apache with its mod_ssl still accesses only the old library `libeay32.dll` from OpenSSL itself but not the new implemented LibreSSL library `libssl-32.dll`

So how do i need to patch/configure/modify Apache (mod_ssl) to access the LibreSSL library which includes the `CHACHA20-POLY1305`-Ciphers?

Thank you.

Comment: ***"So is there any way to get CHACHA20-POLY1305 Ciphers working on Windows?"*** - Yes. But until you tell use the particular problems you are having, there's nothing we can do to assist.

Comment: Updated my first post*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for OpenSSL to support ChaCha20:
https://www.openssl.org/policies/roadmap.html#forthcoming

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am waiting until it is supported :-)